# Elasticsearch. Is it possible to set mapping for field in index for all types?

Tags: types, elasticsearch, mapping

An Elasticsearch cluster can contain multiple Indices (databases), which in turn contain multiple Types (tables).
Is it possible to set mapping for field in index for all types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [_default_](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-mapper.html#_default_mapping) mapping setting on the Index.  When the type is created it will have the field mapping your looking for.

```
PUT /my_index{
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "analyzed"
                }
             }
     }
}
```

You could also use an [Index Template](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-templates.html),  if you wanted all new indexes to have this default setting.  I think it would be a good enhancement to have a [Dynamic Templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates) be available at Index Level so they can be applied across types.  This doesn't appear possible now.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. However do you know the way how to set default mapping for all indexes?

Comment: Yes,  use an Index Template.  See the bottom paragraph in my answer. :)

Comment: Is 'field1' the name of a field in your index?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make use of a multi index PUT Request:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#put-mapping-multi-index